# item.config in Tkinter execute together

Tags: python, tkinter

I am coding in python2.7 using Tkinter. 
I need a set of rectangles to change color one after another. But when I write the item.config one after one in my function, they execute together at the end of the execution.

```
 def button(self):        
        print "hi"
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.figure1, fill="green")
        time.sleep(3)
        print "hello"
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.figure2, fill="green")
        time.sleep(3)
        print "okay"
        time.sleep(3)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.figure3, fill="green")
```

When I run this, all the print statements complete and then the three figures change color together. I need it to change one after the other as each statement gets executed/printed.

I am new to Python and Tkinter. Any suggestions and ideas why this is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example that demonstrates how to perform a chain of actions using [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) to delay events while keeping the Tk event loop running. I only have Python 3 so you may need to modify slightly to work with Python 2.7.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *

def toggle(canvas, items):
    if len(items) > 0:
        canvas.itemconfigure(items[0], fill="green")
        canvas.after(1000, lambda: toggle(canvas, items[1:]))
    return

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, background="white")
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
figure1 = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,80,80, fill="red")
figure2 = canvas.create_rectangle(100,10,180,80, fill="red")
figure3 = canvas.create_rectangle(200,10,280,80, fill="red")
canvas.after(1000, lambda: toggle(canvas, [figure1, figure2, figure3]))
root.mainloop()
```

Keeping the event loop operating is crucial. You cannot use `sleep` in GUI applications unless you create a worker thread. Typically you don't need to anyway. The `after` call puts a task onto the UI event queue for you to be run at a later time and if you capture the after token you can even cancel them (for instance if you require a timeout function for something.).

Comment: Thanks for your input! But if I want some steps to execute between two toggle function calls, like say a print statement, the color change seems to occur together.

Comment: root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, background="white")
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
figure1 = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,80,80, fill="red")
figure2 = canvas.create_rectangle(100,10,180,80, fill="red")
figure3 = canvas.create_rectangle(200,10,280,80, fill="red")
canvas.after(1000, lambda: toggle(canvas, [figure1]))
print "hello"
canvas.after(1000, lambda: toggle(canvas, [figure2]))
root.mainloop()

Comment: @AbinayaSegar You set both `after` calls to 1000, so both will be executed after one second. Try to set the time of the second one to 2000. Keep in mind that the calls to `after` return immediately and schedule a task to be executed some time later, so the two after calls and the print statement will all be executed at almost the same time.

Comment: I assumed after executes 1000ms after the previous statement. Now I get it :)